# xampp 1.8.1. server started, but alias not working

Tags: apache, xampp, alias

I have upgraded to xampp 1.8.1 successfully. Apache and MySQL server start up fine.

However, I just can't get my aliases to work in httpd.conf . IE cannot display page

I have:

```
Alias /tnl "H:northern_light"
<Directory "H:northern_light">
     DirectoryIndex index.php    
     Options All
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried many options. Also, I have tried changing port on Apache.

have tried 127.0.0.1/tnl, localhost/tnl etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Directory options to:

```
    Alias /tnl "H:/northern_light"
    <Directory "H:/northern_light">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I personally use: "Indexes MultiViews" instead of "none" on Options to allow directory index.
Like this:

```
    Alias /tnl "H:/northern_light"
    <Directory "H:/northern_light">
        AllowOverride None
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Acordin to ApacheFriends - Creators of XAMPP

```
# Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
# access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
# Example:
# Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
#
# If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
# need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
# the filesystem path.
```

That means:

Comment: Explain it please, not just Copy&Paste some documentation snippet, what does he need to do in his specific scenario?